# Pandas DataFrame - Count rows between values efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with longitudinal data for many people.  A success flag [0,1] is in one column.

A sample looks like this:

```
  person  success  wait
0    bob        0     0
1    bob        1     1
2    bob        0     0
3    bob        0     1
4    bob        1     2
5    bob        0     0
6   mary        1     1
7   mary        0     0
8   mary        0     1
9   mary        0     2
```

Notice the last column named "wait".  For this example, I calculated it by had.  The wait is the count of 0 in the success column before a 1.  In simple terms, it is, "How many failed attempts before the success.

I can't figure out a way to do this quickly with pandas. My thought was to groupby('person'), and then run some function on the wait column, but don't know what.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your example.  But why does `mary` increase at indexes 8 and 9?  There are no success in that column, typo?  And why does `bob` go back to 0 at 3 and 5?

Comment: It is failures since the lats success.  So at row 8, Mary had one failure (row 7) since her last success (row 6).  For Bob, it resets to 0 at row 2, because he had a success at row 1, and again resets at row 5 because he had a success at row 4.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  I'm not sure that there is a quick way to do this in `pandas`.  Seems like a `for` loop is the way to to go.  Will try a couple of things but a loop would be my first attempt

Comment: Line 6 seems inconsistent. Shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: @Martin, not necessarily if a direct success count as a 1. But indeed needs OP clarification.

Comment: Martin is correct, I made a typo.  Line six should be 0.  Since this is her first attempt, there have been no previous failures.

Comment: upvote for clarifying the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['ix'] = df.groupby('person')['success'].apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(0).append(x.cumsum().head(-1))
).tolist()


df['wait'] = df.groupby(['person','ix']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(len(x)))).tolist()

#In [97]: df
#Out[97]:
#  person  success  wait  ix
#0    bob        0     0   0
#1    bob        1     1   0
#2    bob        0     0   1
#3    bob        0     1   1
#4    bob        1     2   1
#5    bob        0     0   2
#6   mary        1     0   0
#7   mary        0     0   1
#8   mary        0     1   1
#9   mary        0     2   1
```

Comment: That's perfect.  Thank you very much!